# Problem with Thread (bunggecord and spigot)

Tags: minecraft-modding, plugin, bukkit

I would like to see how many players are connected in a server by the way bukkit and Bungee messaging channel like this :

```
public class endawngui extends JavaPlugin implements Listener, PluginMessageListener {


private static endawngui instance;
private int test;


@Override
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;

    getLogger().info(getInstance() + " est activé !");

    this.getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");
    this.getServer().getMessenger().registerIncomingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord", this);

    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(this, this);

}

@Override
public synchronized void onPluginMessageReceived(String channel, Player player, byte[] message) {
    try{
    if (!channel.equals("BungeeCord")) {
        return;
    }
    ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(message);
    if (channel.equals("BungeeCord")) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String input = in.readUTF();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String server = in.readUTF();
        test = in.readInt();
        player.sendMessage(test+"/40");
    }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void playercount(String channel, String target, Player p){
     try{

           ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
           out.writeUTF(target); // PlayerCount
           out.writeUTF(channel); // Server_test
           p.sendPluginMessage(instance, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());

           }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
       }

public synchronized void actplayer(Player p){

    String Server_test = "Server_test";
    String PlayerCount = "PlayerCount";

    playercount(Server_test, PlayerCount, p);

    p.sendMessage("TEST dans la méthode : "+ test);

}
```

When I start my menu the first time the variable was equal to 0
And the second time the variable was equal to 1.

I try to fix this with a method which returns a boolean type. While it's false a Thread.sleep() wait for the response of the bungee channel. But my server crashed. This is my code :

```
package fr.miickadow.endawn;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.DyeColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.messaging.PluginMessageListener;

import com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataInput;
import com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataOutput;
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;


class endawngui extends JavaPlugin implements Listener, PluginMessageListener {
    private static endawngui instance;


private boolean response = false;
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;

    getLogger().info(getInstance() + " est activé !");

    this.getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");
    this.getServer().getMessenger().registerIncomingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord", this);

    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(this, this);
}

private int test;
public int gettest() {
    return test;
}
public void settest(int test) {
    this.test = test;
}
public boolean isResponse() {
    return response;
}
public void setResponse(boolean response) {
    this.response = response;
}
@Override
public synchronized void onPluginMessageReceived(String channel, Player player, byte[] message) {
    try{
    if (!channel.equals("BungeeCord")) {
        return;
    }
    ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(message);
    if (channel.equals("BungeeCord")) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String input = in.readUTF();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String server = in.readUTF();
        int result = in.readInt();
        settest(result);
        setResponse(true);
        player.sendMessage(gettest()+"/40");
    }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public synchronized void playercount(String channel, String target, Player p){
     try{

           ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
           out.writeUTF(target); // PlayerCount
           out.writeUTF(channel); // Server_test
           p.sendPluginMessage(instance, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());

           }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
public synchronized void actplayer(final Player p){
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(this, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            p.sendMessage("TEST dans la méthode : "+ waitForResponse(p));

        }
    });

}

private synchronized int waitForResponse(Player p){
    response = false;
    String Server_test = "Server_test";
    String PlayerCount = "PlayerCount";
    playercount(Server_test, PlayerCount, p);

    while(!isResponse()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return gettest();

}
 public static endawngui getInstance(){
        return instance;
 }

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info(getInstance() + " est désactivé !");

    }
  ...
}
```

Someone can help me please ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Cordially,

Miicka